# WPF Change thickness left border textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, border

I've to change the thickness of a textbox in WPF, but i don't know how to change only one border.

How can i do it?

thi is my code

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="215,144,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" BorderBrush="Red" Margin="215,144,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" BorderThickness="5"/>
```

Apply  Border brush and  set BorderThickness="5,0,0,0" to required thickness.

Comment: this changes all borders, i need only one to change

Comment: `BorderThickness="5 0 0 0"` or such

Answer (score 5):

To set for example the thickness of the left border only, you could write either this:

```
<TextBox BorderThickness="10,0,0,0" .../>
```

or this:

```
<TextBox ...>
    <TextBox.BorderThickness>
        <Thickness Left="10"/>
    </TextBox.BorderThickness>
</TextBox>
```